# IPC Pipe in Linux C

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor, stdio

It's a simple code which makes two child processes communicate: first one execute "ls" and pass the output into myfd[1]; second one receives the output from myfd[0], and then execute "sort"(and shows the result). The parent process waits for these two processes.

But this code doesn't work. It gets stuck at the second child process. Any possible reason why?
Did I use the right "close" and "dump" in proper place?

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pid;
    int wpid;
    int status = 0;

    int myfd[2];

    printf("parent's pid: %d\n",getpid());

    pipe(myfd);

    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0) // child 1 - execute "ls"
    {
        printf("child1's pid: %d\n",getpid());

        close(1);
        dup(myfd[1]);
        close(0);
        close(myfd[0]);

        execlp("ls","child_process1",NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0) // child 2 - execute "sort"
        {
            printf("child2's pid: %d\n",getpid());

            close(myfd[1]);
            close(0);
            dup(myfd[0]);

            execlp("sort","child_process2",NULL);
        }
    }

    // parent
    while((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        // wait until two child processes finish
    }
    printf("done!\n");
}
```

Comment: your code seems to make a lot of assumptions to input. anyway, i don't think you should wait for child 1 to finished before launching child2. instead, child 2 should be launched before child 1 is launched, since you are using a pipe passing child1's output to child2, child2 has to be ready before receiving any data.

Comment: and i think you will need `dup2(2)` to make sure you redirect the right fd.

Comment: i simplifed the code, and revised the code not to make child 2 wait for child 1. but it still doesn't work. what can be the problem?

Comment: is there anything print on the screen? i have some advices here: 1. try to make sure `sort` is ready before `ls` starts; 2. use `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` to make thing easier; 3. use `dup2(2)` instead; 4. make `args[0]` of each command itself, i.e. `execlp("ls","ls",NULL);`. some particular shell will do something stupid if you don't this.

Comment: In the parent, before the `wait`, close myfd[0] and myfd[1].  The parent has both ends of the pipe open too.  child2 will never see EOF on the input pipe as long as the parent has it open.

Comment: @Duck Thanks so much!! that was the exact problem! problem solved!

Comment: @Charlie Ko, you are very welcome.  HuStmpHrrr offered good advice with 3 & 4. `dup2` is preferable in most cases and your `execlp` is on the funky side.  I would add that you should always check your return codes.  It's tedious coding...right up until it saves you from banging your head on the desk for 24 hours. ;)